# Add a button in order list public/user Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add a button in the list of order, in the panel user.

Did you know the hook to use ?

Thanks

Place where i Want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions` where you can add your new action. You can use conditions depending on your needs. You can access order too if you need to build dynamic urls.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'custom_order_button', 10, 2 );
function custom_order_button($actions, $order) {
    // If you need order_id for dynamic stuff
    // $order_id = $order->ID;    
    $actions['my_button_action_name'] = array(
        'url' =>  "https://google.com",
        'name' => __( 'My button', 'woocommerce' )
    );
    return $actions;
}
```